# Contraseña hash laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto en laravel, requiero una opción para poder enviar un correo con las claves de acceso del usuario en donde viene la contraseña. El problema es que las contraseñas las tengo encriptadas. Hay alguna opción que me permita desencriptar dicha información o alguna otra forma de poder encriptar la contraseña y poder desencriptarla para funcionalidades especificas como la que comento?

Answer (score 3):

Empecemos por mencionar algunos puntos:

1. Si te diriges a **`app/config/hashing.php`** notarás que:

- El driver *default* usado para el hashing de contraseñas es *bcrypt*
- Laravel brinda además soporte (de acuerdo con los comentarios del código fuente) además para:

  - argon
  - argon2id

No olvidemos que Laravel sigue siendo en su base PHP, por tanto podemos irnos a la propia [documentación de dicho lenguaje](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-description) donde notarás que nos dice para la función `hash` y cito:

> crea un nuevo hash de contraseña usando un algoritmo de hash fuerte de único sentido

Aquí recalco la parte que dice: **de un único sentido**

Pudieras preguntar ¿pero esta función que tiene que ver con Laravel y mi duda expuesta?

La cuestión es que desde PHP 5.5.0 el algoritmo default que se implementa es precisamente *bcrypt*

Entonces desde mi pobre conocimiento te comento que no veo factible que logres la opción planteada (*por todo lo que a su alrededor involucra*), además para mi **esta totalmente ok** que las contaseñas estén como *hash* en tu base de datos.

Comentarios finales:

- Te recomiendo mucho leas el apartado de [**Configuration**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#configuration) en la documentación de Laravel tiene un par de enlaces muy interesantes que te nutrirán mucho en cuanto a este tema.
- Tal vez debas replantear la forma de que tus usuarios tengan sus credenciales
- Puedes precisamente hablando de Laravel tomar como punto de partida el *scaffolding* generado por alguno de los [paquetes de autenticación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits) y notar como no existe una opción en la que el usuario pueda ver su contraseña como texto plano si no que podrá generar una nueva a través de un sistema de recuperación de contraseña (*esto ya nos dice mucho ¿no?*)

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con la explicación de @BetaM, por ningún motivo se debe poder descifrar las contraseñas de los usuarios. Yo tuve que cambiar el algoritmo de hasheo, dado que un cliente continuaba utilizando sha1, y creo que para que te des una idea de como funciona, ya la implementación del algoritmo depende de ti.

El servicio de Hasheo se encuentra en `config/app.php`

`Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider`

Esta clase utiliza a `Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager` quien implementa los algoritmos.
Lo que realizé fue.
Primero, crear la clase que genera el sha1 de la cadena

```
namespace App\Hashing;

use Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

/**
 * Class Sha1Hasher
 * @package App\Hashing
 */
class Sha1Hasher extends AbstractHasher implements HasherContract
{

    /**
     * Hash the given value.
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @param array $options
     * @return string
     */
    public function make($value, array $options = [])
    {
        $hash = sha1($value);
        return $hash;
    }

    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {
        return sha1($value) === $hashedValue;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the given hash has been hashed using the given options.
     *
     * @param string $hashedValue
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Segundo extendí la clase `Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager`, para registrar el generador de mi hash

```
namespace App\Hashing;

use Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager as Base;

/**
 * Class HashManager
 * @package App\Hashing
 */
class HashManager extends Base
{
    public function createSha1Driver()
    {
        return new Sha1Hasher();
    }
}
```

Tercero, extendí también `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider` para registrar mi propio `HashManager` que ya incluye el hash para sha1

```
namespace App\Hashing;

use Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class Provider
 * @package App\Hashing
 */
class Provider extends HashServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function ($app) {
            return new HashManager($app);
        });

        $this->app->singleton('hash.driver', function ($app) {
            return $app['hash']->driver();
        });
    }
}
```

Habiendo completado esto, tengo que cambiar el `HashProvider` en mi archivo `config/app.php`

```
// Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class, // Provedor por default
App\Hashing\Provider::class, // Provedor con nueva funcionalidad
```

una vez hecho esto, puedo colocar en mi archivo `config/hashing.php`, si quiero que mi default sea sha1

```
...
    'driver' => 'sha1',
```

o simplemente al hacer un hash con `\Hash::driver('sha1')->make('p@s5w0rd')`

Ojo, `'sha1'`, se convierte a `Str::studly(..)` para poder llamar a la función `createSha1Driver` en el `HashManager`.

En la carpeta `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/` puedes hechar un vistazo de los algoritmos que trae por default y su funcionamiento.